# Remote database connection with spring boot

Tags: mysql, database, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have connected remote database by following below properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<server-ip>:3306/db_name
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

I didn't get any error of database while building application.
All crud operations are successfully done without any error while testing the application in local.
But data is not updating in remote database. I didn't catch the issue.
Could you please help me to solve that issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, surely the data goes *somewhere*. Are you sure you're looking for the data in the correct DB schema? Are there any logs that state which database the app connects to?

Comment: Thank you.
Yes, I am checking correct DB for the data.